# xsl: case insensitive replace substring

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, replace, case-insensitive

I need to replace a word (part of a word) in an unknown text. "replace" works fine, but it is case sensitive. How do I replace in a case insensitive way?

Thanks alot!

Comment: We can all agree on the meaning of "case-insensitive search", but what is "case-insensitive replace"?  Please provide an example of what you mean.

Comment: Lets assume you have a unknown text of some sort. This text may contain the string "test", or "Test", even "TeSt". You may want to replace all "/test/i". I know how this works in regular expression, but how does this work in xsl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set flag `i` - ignore case option. Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#flags

Comment: That did the trick. "replace" offers a third argument, which may be the case-insensitive flag. Thank you!